# jQuery automatically trim values

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a little interface where I display an IP address and I am looking for a method to have it automatically trimmed in order to only showcase the last digits.

Example:

```
    <p><strong>Room: </strong>123.123.123.101</p>
```

Ideal outcome:

```
    <p><strong>Room: </strong>101</p>
```

Is there an easy method to have this achieved within jQuery?

Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p><strong>Room: </strong><span class='ip'>123.123.123.101</span></p>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.ip').each(function(){
     var data = $.trim($(this).html()); //using $.trim() here is optional as it is used to remove white spaces only. 
     data = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
     $(this).html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Exception, this seems to trim the first three ip values greatly, however the final output is ".101" is there a way to have the dot removed?

Comment: @dvoip...see updated answer... '+1' with lastindexof

Comment: You're a genius ! Thank you so much Exception it works absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 1):

if the format is permanent for

```
<p><strong>Room:</strong><span>123.123.123.101</span></p>
```

here is the simplest way

```
$('p').text().split('.')[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest wrapping it in a seperate element to make the selection easier

```
<p><strong>Room:</strong><span>123.123.123.101</span></p>
```

After that, you can simply select the value, and use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to transform the string into an array, which makes it easy to select the last digits by accessing the last element of the array.

```
var value = $('p span').html();
var valueArray = value.split('.');

value = valueArray[valueArray.length-1];

$('p span').html(value)
```